# Fast Granger Test/ Wald Test on large number of samples

Tags: r

I have two vectors `x` and `y`

```
x = c(1, -0.0023, -0.001, 0.0077, 0.0011, -0.0039, 3e-04, 0.0068, 
0.0134, 0.0143, 3e-04, 0.0026, 0.0033, 0.0056, -0.01, -0.0012, 
0.0052, 0.0061, -3e-04, -6e-04, 0.005, 0.006, 0.0249, 0.0066, 
0.0147, 0.0019, -0.0092, -0.001, 0.0027, -0.0196, 0.0211, 0.0016, 
-0.0112, -0.0065, 0.0035, 0.0157, -0.0085, 0.0062, 0, -0.0085, 
0.0163, 0.014, -0.0148, -1e-04, -0.0057, 0.0051, -0.0071, 0.0016, 
0.0066, 0.0033)
y = c(1, -0.0066, -0.015, 0.0017, -8e-04, -0.0177, -0.0026, 0.0068, 
0.0521, 0.0525, 0.0091, 0.0015, 0.0209, 0.0022, -0.0067, 0.0074, 
0.0132, 0.0094, 0.0029, 0.0178, 0.0154, 0.0076, 0.0551, 0.0194, 
0.0402, -0.0143, -0.0094, -0.0101, 0.0044, -0.0507, 0.0392, 0.0184, 
-0.0051, 0.0038, 0.0119, 0.0289, -0.0079, 0.0073, -0.0104, -0.0142, 
0.0366, 0.0301, -6e-04, 0.0075, -0.0029, 0.0035, -0.018, 0.0012, 
0.0088, -0.0117)
```

I am trying to run `lmtest::waldtest` on these vectors to find causality.

Method 1 works perfectly -

**Method 1**

```
  fit_1 = lm(x ~ y)
  lmtest::waldtest(fit_1, test = "F")
```

The intent is to make `Method 1` run faster since I am running `wald test` on millions of samples. To improve performance over `Method 1`, I have written two other methods (2 and 3) and both of them are throwing errors as shown below.

**Method 2** - Since my data is in data.table format, I will prefer to execute `lm` directly on data.table columns for improving performance.

```
  library(data.table)
  dt = data.table(x, y)
  fit_2 = lm(x ~ y, data = dt)
  lmtest::waldtest(fit_2, test = "F")

Error in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

**Method 3** - Since fastLM is much faster than `lm` function

```
  fit_3 = RcppArmadillo::fastLm(x ~ y)
  lmtest::waldtest(fit_3, test = "F")

Error in fastLm.formula(formula = x ~ 1) : 
  could not find function "fastLm.formula"
```

**Q1.** Can someone point out why Method 2 and Method 3 fail and are there ways to fix these?

**Q2.** And is there any other way to make Method 1 faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These procedures fail because `waldtest()` is looking for attributes/methods that don't exist in/for fitted model objects returned by `fast.lm()` and `lm()` with data.table input and I don't believe there is an easy fix.

However, if you want to test whether the model including `y` and a constant is "better" than the constant-only model you can use `summary()` (which *has* a method for objects of class `fast.lm`).

E.g. from the last line of `summary(fit_3)` you'll get

```
F-statistic:  5253 on 1 and 48 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

which is equivalent to the result of `waldtest()`:

```r
lmtest::waldtest(fit_1, test = "F")

Wald test

Model 1: x ~ y
Model 2: x ~ 1
  Res.Df Df      F    Pr(>F)    
1     48                        
2     49 -1 5253.1 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: It's not a methods issue for `lm()` with a `data.frame`, but a deeply nested namespace issue actually as `dt` is reserved by `stats`!

Comment: Ah.. good point, didn't think about `stats::dt()`!

Comment: Ha, I almost didn't either and had to dig deep to figure out what was happening. Your method above is probably most appropriate anyway for speed at least!

Comment: This solution improved the performance most. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so, let's start with **Method 3**. Very simply, we can see from the documentation for `?lmtest::wildest` there is no method defined for a `fastLm` object and the default is failing. **@Martin** has a good explanation for how to use `fast.lm()`

For **Method 2** however, you are actually running into namespace conflicts in the function calls. The issue is that `dt` is a reserved name in `stats::dt`.

```r
> lmtest::waldtest(fit_2, test = "F")
#> Error in model.frame.default(formula = x ~ 1, data = dt, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list
> traceback()
#> 14: stop("'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list")
#> 13: model.frame.default(formula = x ~ 1, data = dt, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
#> 12: stats::model.frame(formula = x ~ 1, data = dt, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
#> 11: eval(mf, parent.frame())
#> 10: eval(mf, parent.frame())
#> 9: lm(formula = x ~ 1, data = dt)
#> 8: eval(call, parent.frame())
#> 7: eval(call, parent.frame())
#> 6: update.default(fm, update)
#> 5: update0(fm, update)
#> 4: modelUpdate(objects[[i - 1]], objects[[i]])
#> 3: waldtest.default(object, . ~ 1, test = match.arg(test))
#> 2: waldtest.lm(fit_2, test = "F")
#> 1: lmtest::waldtest(fit_2, test = "F")
```

In `update.default`, 6th in the `traceback()`, the final line run is:

```r
eval(call, parent.frame())
```

In this case, `call == lm(formula = x ~ 1, data = dt)`. So, when this is run in the `parent.frame`, rather than accessing the `data.table` `dt`, it's pulling in the `stats::dt` function. There's a lot of documentation elsewhere from people smarter than myself on namespaces, parent frames, and environments, so won't go into detail here. However, your solution should just be to rename `dt`.

```r
dt2 = data.table(x, y)
fit_2 = lm(x ~ y, data = dt2)
lmtest::waldtest(fit_2, test = "F")
#> Wald test
#> 
#> Model 1: x ~ y
#> Model 2: x ~ 1
#>   Res.Df Df      F    Pr(>F)    
#> 1     48                        
#> 2     49 -1 5253.1 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Comment: Thanks, @caldwellst. You have nailed the reason for error. ```Method 2``` is working fine now.